# Javascript - concatenation of object variables from string

Tags: javascript, string, object, concatenation

Help pls.

We have object:

```
let obj = {
hasError: {
    income_manager: {
      signatory_id: false,
    }
  },
};
```

and string:

```
let halfObject = "income_manager.signatory_id";
```

how can i splice a string with objects to write a new value?

example:

```
let variable = halfObject.split('.')

obj.hasError[variable[0]][variable[1]] = true;
```

But it doesn't look good. Do you have a prettier example?

Comment: what does "not good" mean? Looks like it should work fine to me, if you replace `that` with `obj`. (No idea where `that` comes from.)

Comment: Perhaps you would prefer destructuring assignment, for example: `let [a, p] = e.split('.'); c.r[a][p] = true`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let obj = {
  hasError: {
    income_manager: {
      signatory_id: false
    }
  }
};

let halfObject = "income_manager.signatory_id";

let variable = halfObject.split('.');

obj.hasError[variable[0]][variable[1]] = true;

console.log(obj.hasError[variable[0]][variable[1]]);
```

Comment: Seems to be the same as the OP already has? Or did they add that to their question after you posted?

Comment: @Felix Kling Yeah, with the exception of them referencing "that" instead of "obj".

Comment: I see. But I don't think that really addresses the OPs issue.

Comment: Yes. I know this, but I'm trying to find another way. More beautiful)